# dispatch_semaphore_create in protobuf causes memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, protocol-buffers, semaphore

I use protoBuf in my app to communicate with server, after instrumenting the app I figured that initializing any new protoBuf object causes a new leak. I've search a lot about this issue but could not find anything helpful.

my project uses ARC and protoBuf does not, I added "-fno-objc-arc" flag in build phases so compiler does not use ARC for protoBuf classes.

heres the code that protoBuf uses to initialize new instances:

```
+ (instancetype)message {
  return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (instancetype)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
    messageStorage_ = (GPBMessage_StoragePtr)(((uint8_t *)self) + class_getInstanceSize([self class]));
    readOnlySemaphore_ = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
   }
}
```

I call `[newProtoBufInstance message]` method to create new instances.

and heres instrument leak tool's call tree:

[instrument leak tool's call tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MakjR.png)

Comment: If protoBuf isn't using ARC, then it needs to dispatch_release() the semaphores when it's done with them.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1496328-dispatch_release

Comment: @TyR thanks, as this is a complied version and I should not change it on my own, do you think i should add a ticket in protobuf github so they could debug it?

Comment: Yes it sounds like a good bug report to me